# Failed to start minikube on Monterey

Tags: minikube

I tried to install minikube via below steps on my Monterey:

1.brew install docker

2.download virtualbox 6.1 from https://www.virtualbox.org/ and install

3.`curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-amd64 sudo install minikube-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube` 
(it seems homebrew no longer supports virtualbox and minikube?)

then, I tried to start minikube:
`minikube start --driver=virtualbox`

but got below errors:

```
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'

stderr:
W0707 14:15:11.219566    7860 initconfiguration.go:120] Usage of CRI endpoints without URL scheme is deprecated and can cause kubelet errors in the future. Automatically prepending scheme "unix" to the "criSocket" with value "/var/run/cri-dockerd.sock". Please update your configuration!
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

  Suggestion: Check output of 'journalctl -xeu kubelet', try passing --extra-config=kubelet.cgroup-driver=systemd to minikube start
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4172
```

any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me today

```
minikube delete --all
minikube start --force-systemd
```

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14561